# Passing type names to initialize later in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have created a generic paginated menu that takes a one or more views.

```
struct PagesView: View {
    let pageViews: [AnyView]
    ...
```

I now pass the pages` views as following.

```
PagesView(
    pageViews: [
        AnyView(FirstPageView(args)),
        AnyView(SecondPageView(args)),
        ...
    ]
)
```

However, is it possible to pass the views by struct name, like this?

```
PagesView(
    pageViews: [
        FirstPageView,
        SecondPageView,
        ...
    ]
)
```

And in the `PagesView` initialize the structs? The reason is that in the PagesView I would like to calculate some values to pass to the pages` views.

I imagine I could also use a render method that initializes and returns a view, however that seems ugly to me.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not in SwiftUI design. Even if you make it work somehow be prepared to many strange issues in run-time. Just in case.

Comment: Thank you for the edit and comment. I see, any recommendations? Like hardcoding the possible pages combinations and passing an Enum for the right combination?

Comment: Yes, kind of. It can be created some UI configurator class with properties depending on which the views are inserted or removed. Such configurator instance can be injected into view hierarchy either as environment key or environment object, so it can be accessible at any view level for decision making.